# Delete files older than 180 days based on file name date

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to write a batch file (that works with windows command prompt) which would delete all files which are older than 180 days in a specific folder, but based on the date written **in the file name** and not the modification date of the files.

Here are how the files are named in the folder, they all follow this specific template : **Backup_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_FileName.ext**

I found multiple examples on different websites but they were all refering to the modification dates of the files.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Switch to PowerShell if it's an acceptable option for you - because of awkward date and time manipulation in batch-file.

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ for your answer. Unfortunately, scripting is locked on our computers with that application. I'm stuck with batch files I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file uses a brute force method to calculate the subtraction of 180 days from the current day using a little trickery with the `XCOPY` command. There are alot better and quicker ways to get the subtracted date by converting the dates to julian dates in batch file. But I have always used this one because I understand it and I normally only have to go back a week or two with all of my work stuff.

Powershell or any other Windows scripting language like Jscript or Vbscript would be a better solution for getting the date.  With Powershell you could in theory call it from your batch file with one line of code to get the date within a split second.

```
PowerShell -Command "&{((Get-Date).AddDays(-180)).ToString('yyyyMMdd')}"
```

Regardless of all that, here is pure batch file solution. Set the folder variable to where your files exist. When you are satisfied with the output on the screen remove the word `ECHO` from this line of the code: `echo del "%%G_%%H_%%I"`. This is just a safety precaution for testing. Once you remove the echo it will then delete the files.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folder=C:\some folder\sub folder"

REM set the number of days to substract
SET DAYS=180

REM Call function to check if the date is valid.
CALL :validdate "%days%" subdate
echo Older than: %subdate%
pushd "%folder%"

REM Get a list of the files
REM file pattern is: Backup_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_FileName.ext
set "search=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=_" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b Backup_*_*.* 2^>nul ^|findstr /I /R /C:"^backup_%search%_*.*"') DO (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "fdate=%%H"
    set "fdate=!fdate:~0,8!"
    IF !fdate! lss %subdate% echo del "%%G_%%H_%%I"
    endlocal
)
popd
pause

endlocal
GOTO :EOF

:validdate
setlocal
set "day=%~1"
set rand=%random%
md "%temp%\dummy%rand%\empty%rand%"

REM Get todays date
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"

REM set year month and day into its own variables.
set /a y=%dt:~0,4%
set /a m=1%dt:~4,2%
set /a d=1%dt:~6,2%

:loop
if "%day%"=="0" (
    rd /s /q "%temp%\dummy%rand%"
    endlocal &set "%~2=%y%%m:~-2%%d:~-2%"
    GOTO :EOF
)
set /a d-=1

if %d% lss 101 (
    set d=131
    set /a m-=1

    if %m% lss 101 (
        set m=112
        set /a y-=1
    )
)

xcopy /d:%m:~-2%-%d:~-2%-%y% /t "%temp%\dummy%rand%\empty%rand%" "%temp%\dummy%rand%" >nul 2>&1 && (set /a day-=1 & goto loop) || goto loop

GOTO :EOF
```

Here is an example of me using it on my system.  I first show you a directory listing of all the backup files then I run the batch file to show you what files it will delete and what the subtracted date is.

```
C:\BatchFiles\DATE_TIME_FUNCTIONS>dir /b backup*
Backup_20170504013002_FileName.txt
Backup_20170505093002_FileName.txt
Backup_20170506113002_FileName.txt
Backup_20170507123002_FileName.txt

C:\BatchFiles\DATE_TIME_FUNCTIONS>DeleteFiles.bat
Older than: 20170506
del "Backup_20170504013002_FileName.txt"
del "Backup_20170505093002_FileName.txt"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now my subtract date function will slow down slightly because it uses a loop to get the subtracted date.  The more days you have to subtract the longer it will take to run.  Although at this stage it really isn't that much time just to subtract back to the last leap day. Was only about 5 seconds on my computer.

But this code uses a nice algorithm to use the julian date to do the date math. It is much quicker than my previous code at calculating the date.

```
@echo off
setlocal

Call :GetDateTime Year Month Day
Call :SubtractDate %Year% %Month% %Day% -613 Ret

echo subdate: %Ret%
pause
GOTO :EOF

:SubtractDate Year Month Day <+/-Days> Ret
::Adapted from DosTips Functions::
setlocal & set a=%4
set "yy=%~1"&set "mm=%~2"&set "dd=%~3"
set /a "yy=10000%yy% %%10000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"
if %yy% LSS 100 set /a yy+=2000 &rem Adds 2000 to two digit years
set /a JD=dd-32075+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4
if %a:~0,1% equ + (set /a JD=%JD%+%a:~1%) else set /a JD=%JD%-%a:~1%
set /a L= %JD%+68569,     N= 4*L/146097, L= L-(146097*N+3)/4, I= 4000*(L+1)/1461001
set /a L= L-1461*I/4+31, J= 80*L/2447,  K= L-2447*J/80,      L= J/11
set /a J= J+2-12*L,      I= 100*(N-49)+I+L
set /a YYYY= I, MM=100+J, DD=100+K
set MM=%MM:~-2% & set DD=%DD:~-2%
set ret=%YYYY: =%%MM: =%%DD: =%
endlocal & set %~5=%ret%
exit /b

:GetDateTime Year Month Day Hour Minute Second
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
( ENDLOCAL
   IF "%~1" NEQ "" set "%~1=%YYYY%" 
   IF "%~2" NEQ "" set "%~2=%MM%" 
   IF "%~3" NEQ "" set "%~3=%DD%"
   IF "%~4" NEQ "" set "%~4=%HH%" 
   IF "%~5" NEQ "" set "%~5=%Min%"
   IF "%~6" NEQ "" set "%~6=%Sec%"
)
exit /b
```

Comment: I know this is an older post, but I am new to this code and am trying to duplicate this, but I can't get it to work.  The only thing that is different is my folder path.  Also, I had to change "dir" in the FOR loop to "folder" to reflect the variable "folder" set at the beginning of the code.  Everything else is identical, but all I get is the echo "older than" and then "press any key to continue."  The code doesn't seem to go through the FOR loop for some reason.  Thanks for any leads.